# Pyspark error- Invalid argument, not a string or column

Tags: pyspark, qubole

I have a dataframe in Pyspark -  df_all. It has some data and need to do the following

```
count = ceil(df_all.count()/1000000)
```

It gives the following error

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 0.914914 of type <class ‘float’>. For column literals, use ‘lit’, ‘array’, ‘struct’ or ‘create_map’ function.
```

How can I use ceil function in pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like for your requirement, this would be suitable:

```
import math

count = math.ceil(df_all.count()/1000000)
```